# DoCmd.OpenForm Not Working with Multiple Databases in one File

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am at a loss here.... I am fairly new to Access, but I have already done the DoCmd.OpenForm in 2 other databases and it worked just fine once I found the right code to use.

So this is what I've done.  I originally had 3 separate databases (separate Access files) before realizing you could create multiple databases within one Access file.  They are garden related: Seed Catalog, Flower Seed Starting Journal, and Vegetable Seed Starting Journal.  With the Seed Catalog opened, I imported all the tables, forms, and reports from the other 2 databases so everything is in one Access file now, saved as 'Seed Journal.'

I have one report titled "Not Germinated - Flowers."  This is the frustrating part.  I opened the "Flower Seed Starting Journal" database that was separate and on it's own, and the following code/event builder works perfectly in opening the specific form (based on ID) when I click on the Seed Name in the report (which is what I want, in case I want to edit my notes for that one):

```
Private Sub Seed_Name_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Flower Seed Journal", acNormal, , "id = " & Me.ID, acFormEdit
End Sub
```

However, when I go to the new database with all 3 previous databases in the same Access file, the code above does not work.  When I go back to report view, nothing happens when I click on the seed name.  No errors pop up regarding debugging.  Just nothing.  I am at a loss as to why it works in one place and not the other.  Here is a screenshot of the Access Objects for reference.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

[Screenshot of Access Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0U6u.jpg)

Comment: Rebuild the RecordSource of the form.

Comment: So I went in a did a query where I selected and dragged all fields from the appropriate table to the form for the RecordSource.  But still nothing.  Is that how you rebuild it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You show a report, but open a form - by clicking a textbox? Normally, you view and/or print a report, that's all.

Comment: I figured it out.  I probably don't use Access the way most do.  I wanted to click a seed name in a report so it would open that specific form entry as I have notes outlined for various seed types.  I don't ever really print anything.  I just view the info in the form on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue finally, in case anyone else has this problem.  I had to go in under "Info" and mark it as trusted content.  Once I did that, I was able to click the seed name in the report to take me to the form I had created for that specific seed type to view details should I need to.